# Want two Vertices off the same Edge in Gremlin

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I have a graph like this

```
V('Producer')-E('RESPONSIBLE_PRODUCER)->V('Event')<-E('INSPECTED')-V('Engineer')
V('Event')<-E('ALIGNED_PRODUCER')-V('Producer')
```

That is, each 'Event' vertex has two incoming edges: one that terminates at an 'Engineer' vertex and another that terminates at a 'Producer' vertex.  But the function of the Producer vertices are different depend on the edge label.

I want to get the originating Producer, the Event, Engineer and terminating Producer.

I have this gremlin code:

```
g.V().hasLabel('Producer').
as('responsible').
has('ProdId', 1234567).
out("RESPONSIBLE_PRODUCER").hasLabel('Event').as('event').
in("INSPECTED").hasLabel('Engineer').as('engineer').
select('responsible', 'event', 'engineer').
by(valueMap('name')).by(valueMap('name')).by(valueMap('name'))
```

That is, I chose a given Producer and get the Event and Engineer then return some details about each of those vertices.

I also want the Producer aligned to the Event in the same query but am not sure how to do this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `project`:

```
g.V().has('Producer', 'ProdId', '1').as('r').
out("RESPONSIBLE_PRODUCER").hasLabel('Event').
project('responsible', 'event', 'engineer', 'aligned').
by(select('r').values('name')).
by(values('name')).
by(in('INSPECTED').values('name')).
by(in('ALIGNED_PRODUCER').values('name'))
```

You can see a "live" example of your problem [here](https://gremlify.com/1f)

Comment: Yes!  Thank you! Great tool too.

Comment: Display stack trace? [yN]y
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
groovysh_parse: 1: unexpected token: in @ line 1, column 213.
   me')). by(values('name')). by(in('INSPECTED

Yet another reason to HATE Neptune ....

Comment: Not sure if that's the issue with Neptune. But try to add __ to the in command. change 'by(in(..)...' to 'by(__.in(...)...'

Comment: The Gremlin Console is based on the Groovy Console. The Groovy Console parses the input before sending it to a server. In Groovy `in()` is a reserved word so when used as an anonymous traversal (right after an opening parenthesis) it needs to be prefixed with the double under-bar. You will find a list of the reserved words (there are not very many) in the TinkerPop documentation.